# Mongodb php7, Update document by id?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I moved from [mongo](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) to [mongodb](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) extension when I upgraded to PHP7. The only thing I cannot figure out is to update a doc by id. Mongo used to have the MongoId Class to parse the id from string but I can't find any equivalent for Mongodb.

This is where I'm at and which doesn't work

```
$collection->updateOne(['_id' => '567eba6ea0b67b21dc004687'], ['$set' => ['some_property' => 'some_value']]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*?

Comment: it doesn't update the document, like it doesn't find it

Comment: The `mongodb` extension, while it can be used on its own, is intended to be used with the userland `mongo-php-library`: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

Comment: yes, updateOne is from that lib

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `_id` should be a instance of BSON:

```
$collection->updateOne(['_id' => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('567eba6ea0b67b21dc004687')], ['$set' => ['some_property' => 'some_value']]);
```

Comment: Suppose I have an array `$array` which is a copy of the document, except with a few modifications, if i send that array as a second parameter will that work to update the original document?

Comment: @Lixus According to the documentation it should work: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/